# Prevent Eclipse from removing trailing whitespaces

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse removes whitespaces automatically in my Java classes... which is OK.
But if I open a properties-File in the text-editor it does the same... which is not OK.

Any idea how to turn this off?

Comment: The Java editor only does trailing space removal if you configure it in the 'Save Action' preferences. Testing here the 'Properties File Editor' doesn't seem to do this at all.

Comment: Mine does... I am using ecliipse neon 3

Comment: If you have AnyEdit Tools installed: in _Window > Preferences: General > Editors > AnyEdit Tools_, in tab _Auto - Convert_ uncheck _Remove trailing whitespace_

Comment: Re _But if I open a properties-File in the text-editor it does the same..._ => do you literally mean that the act of **opening** a properties file in Eclipse causes any existing trailing spaces in that file to be removed? If not, can you clarify the exact problem?

Comment: @howlger thanks, this solved the problem. Everytime I saved the properties file the trailing whitespaces were removed by anyedit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have [**AnyEdit Tools**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) installed:

In ***Window > Preferences: General > Editors > AnyEdit Tools***, in tab ***Auto - Convert***, in section *Before editor buffer will be saved...* **uncheck *Remove trailing whitespace***.